# ngrx with Angular 2 RC5

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to use ngrx with RC5 but i'm getting some wired behavior. State changes properly get captured by the ngrx log monitor, but they don't get emitted to my subscribers.

But once i change pages (i'm using @angular/router 3) all of my state changes get emitted one by one to the subscribers.

Here is a sample of the code

```
    ngOnInit() {
      this._store.dispatch(this._mediaActions.load());
      this._positionListener = this._store
        .let(getMediaFolderContent())
        .subscribe(a => this.position = a);

      this._store.let(getMediaFolderContent()).subscribe(a => console.log(a));
      this._store.select(s => s.media).subscribe(a => console.log('just a test: ', a));
    }
```

I get the latest state when i first navigate to the page but no subsequent changes get captured. Then again once i navigate from and back to the page i get the state changes.

I know this isn't enough code for a valid question, but there is just so much of it and i wouldn't know where to start copying all of it. I'm just hopping someone has dealt with a similar issue in RC5.

All of the code worked before migrating to RC5.

Comment: The first thing I'd check when there is a state change showing in the monitor but not emitted is that the reducer returns a new object.  Use object.assign liberally.  No new object, = no new emit from the observable.  Might not be it but it is a place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve it. I hope this helps someone.

So the problem was in my reducers what i would do is this:

```
return Object.assign(state, {something: 'something'}
```

But it turns out the state change only gets emitted if i create a new object. So what i had to do was change the assign like this:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {something: 'something'}
```

Thank you @wiredprogrammer for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you show how to add ngrx in rc5? webstorm doesnt let me add provideStore

Comment: Hmm.. I'm also using webstorm and i'm not getting any errors or warnings. Make sure that the provideStore(reducers) is in side of the providers array in you app.module.ts.

Comment: I can't seem to get a plunkr working but here is a simple jsFiddle with my app.module.ts. hope it helps https://jsfiddle.net/czzofLL5/

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. In ngrx/store github they say to add provider like this: StoreModule.provideStore({ counter: counterReducer }, { counter: 0 }). Check it out: https://github.com/ngrx/store

Comment: Wow they just updated that, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I will be heppy if you could upload your project except node_module. I have hard time to install store core+state and "Promise" is not recognized and angualr cli didnt install typings. I'm hopeless :(

Comment: I'll update an ngrx project to github this weekend. Sorry i can't help sooner i'm really short on time over the week.